# Variables scope in inline django shell, vs python shell

Tags: python, django, django-shell

I have problem,  with strange behavior of django shell. I have this code:

```
fields = ('name', 'description', 'long_description', 'foot_description')
a = 1
dict( (field, a) for field in fields)
```

When I run it from python shell it's give me right dict. But when i running it from django shell i get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in     <module>()
----> 1 dict( (field, a) for field in fields)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in    <genexpr>((field,))
----> 1 dict( (field, a) for field in fields)

NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
```

My question is simple: WHY?

Comment: Can't seem to replicate this on my shell. :/

Comment: I can replicate this error in a Django 1.3 IPython shell.

Comment: @aychedee I can't.. `Out[3]: {'description': 1, 'foot_description': 1, 'long_description': 1, 'name': 1}`

Comment: @OP : What version are you on? I can't replicate this on Django 1.5.

Comment: I can replicate it on Django 1.4.1 IPython shell, and Django IPython shell 1.3.7.

Comment: @SukritKalra, maybe you can give us more information about your django version, and os?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be [a known issue and fixed in Django 1.6](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2532/).

For the time being, there is a suggested workaround in the ticket. "Grab the following lines (from here https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/shell.py) and replace the current implementation (...) with this":

```
def ipython(self):
    try:
        from IPython.frontend.terminal.ipapp import TerminalIPythonApp
        app = TerminalIPythonApp.instance()
        app.initialize(argv=[])
        app.start()
    except ImportError:
        # IPython < 0.11
        # Explicitly pass an empty list as arguments, because otherwise
        # IPython would use sys.argv from this script.
        try:
            from IPython.Shell import IPShell
            shell = IPShell(argv=[])
            shell.mainloop()
        except ImportError:
            # IPython not found at all, raise ImportError
            raise
```

You can also try `python manage.py shell --plain`, from a comment on the same ticket.