# Cannot access imported functions in django shell by pipeline command?

Tags: python, django, shell

It is a python script `tshi3.py` :

```
    import csv
    def li2ho2():
        print(csv)
    li2ho2()
```

I copied this code and pasted it in `python manage.py shell`.
It works.

But I ran `python manage.py shell < tshi3.py`.
Got `NameError: name 'csv' is not defined`.

Why?

Enviroment:

```
    Linux Mint 18.1
    Python 3.4.1 (default, Sep  3 2014, 08:45:22) 
    Django==1.11.4
```

There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004417/why-cant-i-access-imported-functions-in-djangos-shell-with-ipython).

Comment: Try `cat | python manage.py shell` and paste the same code once the interpreter loads.. I don't really know if this piping works for manage.py

Comment: My guess is that Django is not properly redirecting the input to shell process

Comment: `cat | python` failed, either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have taken a look at the code of `shell` command. Here it is:

```
if sys.platform != 'win32' and select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0]:
    exec(sys.stdin.read())
    return
```

The problem comes from the exec command is called without passing the `globals` and `locals` parameters, then by default, the `globals()` and `locals()` dictionary of the current scope will be used.

Remember that at module level, globals and locals are the same dictionary, but at the current scope (at django.core.management.commands.shell.Command.handle), globals() and locals() are two different dictionary. And now things become uncontrollable when the code of `tshi3.py` is executed.

Let's go through each line of code:

```
import csv
```

This will import the module `csv` and put it into the `locals()` dictionary. So, if the `locals()` dict is the same as the `globals()` dict, this will also be in the `globals()` dict. BUT, in our case, `csv` is ONLY in the `locals()` dict, NOT in the `globals()` dict.

Next:

```
def li2ho2():
    print(csv)
```

When the command `print(csv)` is called, `csv` will be looked up in the `locals()` dictionary of the function `li2ho2`, and it's surely not there, so `csv` is looked up in the `globals()` dictionary. But as what I wrote above, `csv` is not in `globals()` dictionary, that's why the error: `NameError: name 'csv' is not defined` is raised.

I try changing the code of tshi3.py as below:

```
import csv

print('globals() equals to locals(): {}'.format(globals() == locals()))
print('csv is in globals(): {}'.format('csv' in globals()))
print('csv is in locals(): {}'.format('csv' in locals()))

def li2ho2():
    print('inside li2ho2 function:')
    print('    csv is in globals(): {}'.format('csv' in globals()))
    print('    csv is in locals(): {}'.format('csv' in locals()))

li2ho2()
```

And run it in two different ways:

```
$ python tshi3.py 
globals() equals to locals(): True
csv is in globals(): True
csv is in locals(): True
inside li2ho2 function:
    csv is in globals(): True
    csv is in locals(): False

$ ./manage.py shell < tshi3.py 
globals() equals to locals(): False
csv is in globals(): False
csv is in locals(): True
inside li2ho2 function:
    csv is in globals(): False
    csv is in locals(): False
```

So, you can see it's exactly as what I explained above. This problem can be fixed by passing an empty dictionary as `globals` parameters for the `exec` command as below:

`exec(sys.stdin.read(), {})`

Hope this helps you and I am sorry for not be able to explain the problem shorter.

Comment: exec(sys.stdin.read(), globals()) https://github.com/django/django/blob/db588d4f0edde5095f8975be1da4e693268b86b3/django/core/management/commands/shell.py#L127

Answer (score 5):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45877987/2091324) - manage.py shell command splits globals() and locals(). So, if you need expected behaviour of variables visibility, you should update list of global variables manually with your new imported local variables. Way below is more easily than changing of manage.py shell function:

```
import csv

globals().update(locals())

def li2ho2():
    print(csv)

li2ho2()
```